# Scala: Convert string to lambda

Tags: scala, lambda, reflection

I want to be able to parse strings like `"x => x + 1"` and be able to actually use it as a lambda function like this:

```
    val string = "x => x + 1"
    val lambda = parseLambda(string)
    val numbers = List(1, 2, 3)
    val result = numbers.map(lambda) // Should be [2, 3, 4]
```

I have the following implementation for the `parseLambda` function:

```
  def parseLambda(string: String): Any => Any = {
      val toolbox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
      val tree = toolbox.parse(string)
      val lambdaFunction = toolbox.compile(tree)().asInstanceOf[Any => Any]
      lambdaFunction
  }
```

It works for strings like `"(x: Int) => x * 2"` or `"(s: String) => s.split(" ")"` but if I omit the types e.g. `"x => x * 2"` or `"s => s.split(" ")"` I get the following error

```
';' expected but '=>' found.
```

Is there a way to be able to omit the types in the string? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without type hint `x => x * 2` would fail to compile in both Scala 2 (https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ChqbxOxRSvGhFTsXeyhOWA) and Scala 3 (https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1uYVoRXLTeKEwfoPCwrKzQ). This is simply bad code. `toolkit.parse` is returning rather unhelpful message, but there is no magic way in which compiler would guess what should the input be.

However in your code there is something which knows what the type should be: the type of values in `numbers`.

```
trait TypeName[A] {
  def name: String
}

def parseLambda[Input: TypeName](string: String): Input => Any = {
  val code = s"""val result: ${implicitly[TypeName[Input]].name} => Any = ${string}
                |result
                |""".stripMargin
  val toolbox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
  val tree = toolbox.parse(code)
  val lambdaFunction = toolbox.compile(tree)().asInstanceOf[Input => Any]
  lambdaFunction
}
```

Then it should work:

```
val string = "x => x + 1"
val lambda = parseLambda[Int](string) // Int hinted
val numbers = List(1, 2, 3)
val result = numbers.map(lambda) // Should be [2, 3, 4]

// or

numbers.map(parseLambda(string)) // Int inferred
```

That is, it should work as long as you provide the right `TypeName[A]` instance.

In Scala 2 it should works with something similar to:

```
object TypeName {

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  implicit def provide[A](implicit tag: WeakTypeTag[A]): TypeName[A] =
    new TypeName[A] {
      def name: String = tag.toString() // should work for simple cases
    }
}
```

and for Scala 3 (your code looks like Scala 2, but in case you wanted to port it to 3) something like:

```
object TypeName {

  import scala.quoted.*
  
  def provideImpl[A: Type](using quotes: Quotes): Expr[TypeName[A]] =
    import quotes.*, quotes.reflect.*
    '{
      new TypeName[A] {
        def name: String = ${ TypeRepr.of[A].show(using TypeReprCode) }
      }
    }

  inline given provide[A]: TypeName[A] = ${ TypeName.provideImpl[A] }
}
```

(Disclaimer, I haven't compiled it, so it should be something like that, but might need some adjustments).

What if this type cannot be provided because you don't know? (E.g. if this lambda was sent to you?)

Well, if you don't know the type compiler wouldn't know as well, so you simply cannot do that.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the answer, seems like what I'm looking for!

I'm having some trouble getting the code to work, as I'm not very experienced with scala so I'd like to ask a couple of additional things: 

The main thing is I'm getting an _"method TypeName does not take type arguments"_ error at the line that has the `s"""val result: ${implicit TypeName[Input].name} => Any = ${string}`. We're assuming we're trying to set the type for the input argument, right? But I'm not sure what I should change in order for it to work.

Comment: As I said, I haven't tested it. After putting code in Scastie I notices that I had two typos: stripLines -> strinpMargins and implicit -> implicitly.

Comment: Thank you! I made it work with the changes you mentioned. One other thing; is there a way to be able to get the output type of the lambda, in order to be able to pipe multiple lambdas one after the other?

Comment: Not really. The output is decided in runtime, based on what is the content of the String. At best you could assume some supertype of the output (more detailed than `Any`), check if runtime value matches and upcast or throw. Or you could maintain a "list" of types you "support" and dispatch them in the form of pattern matching. At this point you are using runtime reflection and runtime errors is the only way I can see you could pipe things.