# Scala: Convert Iterable[Any] to the actual type of its content

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, casting

I want to be able cast a generic iterable to the actual type of its contents, but I don't know the type at compile time. Is there a way to have a function like this?

```
def castIterable[IN, OUT](iterable: Iterable[IN]): Iterable[OUT] = {
  iterable.asInstanceOf[Iterable[ figureOutContentType(...) ]]
}
```

Comment: You can use runtime reflection. Documented here for Scala 2: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html#

Comment: Could you give an example? Because it still is not clear to me what I should do. Thank you!

Comment: Question: how do you expect your program to know the return type ? Is it through some kind of inheritance ? Or are you just looking for a generic type conversion ? Either way, using `asInstanceOf` is 99% of the time a bad solution to a wrongly defined problem. By the way not knowing the type at compile time is literally unsound: the compiler **definitely** knows the type (even if you don't). You can maybe look at [match types](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/match-types.html). Please add some more information to your issue.

Comment: It concerns [this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76555850/5589918) where I am creating lambda functions from strings given by the user. Then these lambdas could be used for a `map` operator for example. So a list of `Int` could be mapped to a list of e.g. `String`. But at the moment, the output type of every user defined lambda is `Any` and I want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot express in the type system the type you do not know, because it varies in runtime. At best you can express the knowledge that you know it exists and that something will be of the same type as it.

That's were generics and existential types come into play.

Generic is type system way of expressing *the universal quantification*: for each type X, something follows. `def method[A >: L <: U](a: A) = ...` is a proof that construction, that without any assumption - other than upper and lower bound and a value - the body can be constructed for `A` without knowing the `A`. Inside `method` you only know that `A` exists but not much else! Outside, you can specify it to be whatever you want and obtain a concrete implementation.

Existential type is a type where you know that the type exists, precisely because you received an instance of it. E.g. `def method(opt: Option[?]) = ...`. It's type system encoding of *existential quantification*. It differ from generic in that you don't have a handle for this unknown type.

In practice, if you see `[A, B, ...]` after name it will be generic and if there will be `?` (in Scala 3, in Scala 2 without `-Xsource:3` and other flags there is `_` for existential types, making it easy to confuse with type constructors). But you can often translate one into the other:

```
// The content of Option is some unknown type, an existential type
val option: Option[?] = ...

// This method is defined with generic parameter A
def asString[A]: A => String = _.toString

// Here, compiler applies unknown type to asString
// - we don't know it but since asString can be applied
// FOR EVERY TYPE it must be applicable to our unknown type as well.
option.map(asString)
```

```
// This class has a generic parameter A 
class Foo[A](a: A)

// Here, we made compiler "forget" the exact type applied to A
// turning it into an existential type.
val foo: Foo[?] = new Foo("test")
```

In Scala 3 existential type usage is limited but you can use path-dependent types to express the idea:

```
trait MyType {
  type MyAbstractType

  val value: MyAbstractType

  val function: (MyAbstractType, MyAbstractType) => MyAbstractType
}

// We have no idea what myType.MyAbstractType is...
val myType: MyType = ...

// ...but we can pass values around when we know what this unknown type
// match the type of method arguments etc.
myType.function(myType.value, myType.value)
```

And that leads us to back to your question, the current and [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76555850/5589918).

You want to create something like:

```
val values: List[SomeType] = ...

values
  .map(parsedLambda(string1))
  .map(parsedLambda(string2))
  .map(parsedLambda(string3))
```

where problem is that you cannot compile lambdas without input type (`a => something`). At best you could model the initial input type (that you know) but the rest are types created in runtime, so you won't express them statically.

However, you could model your code with existential types/path-dependent types. A draft that should present the general idea (but not necessarily work) could look like:

```
object Utility {
  class Helper[Input] {
    def apply[Output](f: Input => Output): Input => Output = f
  }
  def fixInputInferOutput[Input] = new Helper[Input]
}

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.*
import scala.tools.reflect.*

trait SomeSequence { self =>
  type ElementType
  val ElementType: String

  val sequence: List[ElementType]

  def parseLambdaAndMap(lambda: String): SomeSequence = {
    val code = s""" Utility.fixInputInferOutput[$ElementType]($lambda) """
    val toolbox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
    val tree = toolbox.parse(code)
    new SomeSequence {
      // The type isn't necessarily Any, but it's easier to implement it that
      // way - the important part is that outside world would have to rely
      // on the ElementType string when chaining the results
      type ElementType = Any
      val ElementType = tree.tpe.finalResultType.typeSymbol.fullName

      val sequence = self.sequence.map(
        toolbox.compile(tree)().asInstanceOf[ElementType => Any]
      )
    }
  }
}
object SomeSequence {
  def apply[A: WeakTypeTag](list: List[A]): SomeSequence = new SomeSequence {
    type ElementType = A
    val ElementType = weakTypeTag[A].toString()

    val sequence = list
  }
}
```

used as

```
SomeSequence(values)
  .parseLambdaAndMap(string1)
  .parseLambdaAndMap(string2)
  .parseLambdaAndMap(string3)
  ...
```

When writing things like that, you are entering into the realm of REPLs, Scastie-like IDes, compilers, probably also lambda serialization a'la Apache Spark. In such case, I'd suggest doing some courses on type theory, compilers, runtime and compile time reflection - to just have a well founded understanding of what you are attempting to do. It is not simple, it cannot be hack together in an evening (unless you *really* know that you're doing), and if it's not for educational purpose I'd suggest trying to use some existing body of work, because it will be only harder from now on.